# Making portions of div transparent

Tags: html, css, transparency

I came across a website that had sections of the main body div transparent, without making the entire body transparent as well.

Was this achieved by blocking divs of different sizes?

Here is the site: https://ethanmarcotte.com/wrote/

Comment: probably the body has an image background fixed and the content containers have a coloured background - the transparent ones have no background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It uses `linear-gradient` background
Take a look at this website: [linear-gradient](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp)

On the mentioned website they used:

```
background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, #FBFBFB 30vw)
```

You can set the color, you can rotate the gradient and you can also add transparency(opacity).
They have a background image on the body and have a div above it with some content and a gradient background.
Take a look at this example:

```css
body{

background:url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/531880/pexels-photo-531880.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=cold-vehicles-water-531880.jpg&fm=jpg) 0 50%,#FEFEFE;
}
#page{
background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, #FBFBFB 30vw);
width: 100%;
height: 400px;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div id="page">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you inspect the page, you can see that it has rgba linear gradient which provides the effect you are looking for. In this specific case it is on the `.page` class:

```
.page {
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, #FBFBFB 30vw);
}
```

Inspecting web pages is good way to learn and experiment. You can try modifying the values directly in dev tools and see the effects immediately on the page.

Answer (score 0):

This web has been achieved using a white background on top of an image.
The white background has the following gradient style:

```
.page {
    background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, #FBFBFB 30vw);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source code of the site the css for the gradient is

```
linear-gradient(135deg, #fff0 0%, #FBFBFB 30vw)
```

Here's a snippet

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  background: url(https://ethanmarcotte.com/dist/img/relief.svg)
}

div {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 90vh;
  margin-top: 10vh;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #fff0 0%, #FBFBFB 30vw);
  text-align: right
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>Here is your Content</div>
</body>
```